# Enrich constraint solver with own proofs

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I have the following type family:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat
type family WrapMaybes (n :: Nat) (a :: *) :: *
type instance WrapMaybes Z a = a
type instance WrapMaybes (S n) a = Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
```

This mostly works as expected, for example `WrapMaybes (S (S Z)) Int ~ Maybe (Maybe Int)`.

Now, obviously (well, except maybe for reasons of termination?!) the following commuting identity holds: `WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) ~ Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)`

GHC by itself is not able to infer that property, so I'm looking for ways to add that axiom, ideally by some supplementary proof. The best I've come up with so far is [coincident overlap in type families](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/coincident-overlap-in-type-families/). But the proposed syntax doesn't seem to work anymore (`type instance where` triggers a syntax error), so I went with just this:

```
type instance WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) = Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
```

But that makes GHC complain again:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
  WrapMaybes 'Z a = a
  WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) = Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)

Conflicting family instance declarations:
  WrapMaybes ('S n) a = Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
  WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) = Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
```

So:

1. Is there a way to make the proposed mechanism work? E.g. How do I get rid of the syntax error?
2. Is coincident overlap still a thing in GHC Haskell?
3. What other mechanism is there to teach GHC the necessary axioms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincident type family overlap is indeed still present in GHC Haskell, as documented [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#compatibility-and-apartness-of-type-family-equations). The examples from the documentation, and the blog post you linked to, are still accepted by GHC 8.4.3.

---

However, I don't think that coincident overlap is going to help you here, because the RHSs aren't (can't) be equal according to the syntactic equality check that GHC uses. Basically, for the coincident overlap type family idea would work, GHC would already have to know the property that you want to "prove".

To actually prove it, you will need to introduce the type equality that you want into the typing environment whenever you need to use this fact. One way to do this is using `:~:` from `Data.Type.Equality`:

```
data a :~: b where  -- See Note [The equality types story] in TysPrim
  Refl :: a :~: a
```

The basic idea here is that when you make a value of type `a :~: b` by using the `Refl` constructor, GHC must know that `a ~ b`. When you later pattern-match on this `Refl` constructor, you are re-introducing this equality into GHC's typing environment. You can use this to build up an inductive proof.

In order to be able to build an inductive proof, however, you will need to be able to branch on the value of the `Nat`, which you can't do while it is entirely at the type level. To get around this, we can introduce a "singleton" GADT:

```
data SNat (n :: Nat) where
  SZ :: SNat 'Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat ('S n)
```

When you pattern-match on a value of type `SNat`, you will introduce information into the typing environment about the value of the type-level natural, due to the GADT structure of the `n` type variable.

This means that we can write a function with a type like this:

```
wrapMaybeComm' :: forall n a. SNat n
               -> WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) :~: Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
```

The idea here is that if you give it a (value-level witness to) a type-level natural `n`, it will return a witness to the fact that `WrapMaybes n (Maybe a)` is the same thing as `Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)`.  When you pattern-match on that witness, GHC will be convinced that the fact is true, and be able to use it.

We can now write a definition for `wrapMaybeComm'` that looks very much like an inductive proof of the necessary fact.  The base case is `0`:

```
wrapMaybeComm' SZ = Refl
```

When `n = 0`, GHC is immediately able to see that `Maybe a ~ Maybe a`.

In the inductive case, we will need to make a call to `wrapMaybeComm'`:

```
wrapMaybeComm' (SS m) = case wrapMaybeComm' @_ @a m of Refl -> Refl
```

Pattern matching on the `Refl` tells GHC that `WrapMaybes m (Maybe a) ~ Maybe (WrapMaybes m a)`, where `n ~ 'S m`.  With this, GHC can see that

```
  WrapMaybes n (Maybe a)
~ WrapMaybes ('S m) (Maybe a)            {- defn. of m -}
~ Maybe (WrapMaybes m (Maybe a))         {- defn. of WrapMaybes -}
~ Maybe (Maybe (WrapMaybes m (Maybe a))) {- IH -}
~ Maybe (WrapMaybes ('S m) (Maybe a))    {- defn. of WrapMaybes -}
~ Maybe (WrapMaybes n (Maybe a))         {- defn of m -}
```

And so knows that the `Refl` on the right side typechecks.

---

If you do not want to have to carry around `SNat`s all over the place, you can replace them with (sometimes quieter) typeclass dictionaries via the definition of a `KnownNat` class like this:

```
class KnownNat (n :: Nat) where
  getSNat :: SNat n
instance KnownNat 'Z where
  getSNat = SZ
instance KnownNat n => KnownNat ('S n) where
  getSNat = SS getSNat
wrapMaybeComm :: forall n a. (KnownNat n)
              => WrapMaybes n (Maybe a) :~: Maybe (WrapMaybes n a)
wrapMaybeComm = wrapMaybeComm' @n @a getSNat
```

To actually use this theorem, whenever you have an expression `e` that GHC refuses to typecheck because it doesn't know the desired equality with `n` and `a`, you can write instead `case wrapMaybeComm @n @a of Refl -> e` and it should work.

---

This approach can be used to teach GHC about all kinds of interesting inductive facts. In the general case, GHC of course cannot be aware of all types that are equal, as this would require it to be able to decide arbitrary theorems of a quite powerful logic system, which is impossible. However, many proofs of interesting inductive theorems can be readily converted into this style, a variant of which (without the extra singletons work) is quite common in dependently typed languages.

---

Side note: to use the above, you will need a few extra GHC Haskell extensions.

- **`-XGADTs`**: The SNat singleton has to be a GADT in order to ensure that one value inhabits every `SNat n` (specifically, the one with `n` `SS`s applied to an `SZ`).
- **`-XScopedTypeVariables`**: This is necessary to ensure that calls to proof functions happen with the correct types.
- **`-XTypeOperators`**: The given code uses `:~:` from `Data.Type.Equality`, which is a type operator. An equivalent definition that is not a type operator (e.g. `Equal a b` instead of `a :~: b`) could, however, have been used.
- **`-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`**: The given definitions have what GHC calls ambiguous types (functions that need extra type signatures and/or visible type applications to disambiguate certain tyvars). This can be worked around by using more `Proxy` parameters.
- **`-XTypeApplications`**: This (the `@tyvar` syntax) was used for convenience in specifying type variables. It should, however, be possible to replace with (somewhat more annoying/verbose) explicit type annotations.

Comment: Btw., `unsafeCoerce Refl` seems to work as a proof that doesn't incur any overhead at run-time.